# Syncing Between Desktop Application and Mobile App

Tags: database, synchronization, desktop-application, mobile-application

We have a desktop application that writes to an Oracle database as the backend. We also have a mobile app which is supposed to be updated with the transactions made on the desktop application.

The desktop application writes the transactions to a web server. This web server is read by the mobile app.

How can we handle the issue of syncing between the desktop application and the mobile app? For instance, if a transaction is written to the Oracle database and the same transaction fails to be written to the web server? or vice versa?

Comment: Dedication to all users: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLvFbBR4XOg . May the force be with you and may you soon answer my question. :o)